# how to clone content and change it in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout, clone

i want to show One new number revealing every day from *96 to *01 by clone 96 and push it in next day
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhL7c.jpg)

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="content">
  <a class="days day-96" style="display:none;">
    *96
  </a>
  <a class="days day-95" style="display:none;">
    *95
  </a>
</div>
```

```
// JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Delay the action by 10000ms
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(".day-96").show();
    }, 0000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".day-95").show();
     }, 5000);

 });
```

Comment: what are you trying to doing

Answer (score 0):

there is the way to clone elements in jquery also similar in vanilla js as well

`.cloneNode(true)` for vanilla js

```js
// JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = $(".days").clone(),
        count = 100
    $(".content").text("")
    while(count){
        var newEl = el.clone()
        newEl.html(count)
        $(".content").append(newEl)
        count--
    }
    animate(100)  // define delay in ms
 });
 
 function animate(delay){
    var i = 0,loop,days=$(".days")
    loop = setInterval(function(){
        if(i < days.length){days.eq(i).addClass("show")}
        else{clearInterval(loop)}
        i++
    },delay)
 }
```

```css
.days {opacity:0;transition:all 0.2s ease;}
.show {opacity:1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.16/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-5D0ofs3AsWoKsspH9kCWlY7qGxnHvdN/Yz2rTNwD9L271Mno85s+5ERo03qk9SUNtdgOZ4A9t8kRDexkvnWByA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="content flex flex-wrap">
  <a class="days border p-2" style="display:block;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you how to Delay the action by one day

Comment: i cant understand what you wanted to delay if you can show some more example of your desired result i can suggest something and if this answer resolves your problem consider accepting it please

Comment: check the updated answer, as far i can understand you were trying to showing one after one div with a delay so i added animate function to simulate that see is it the thing you wanted